# Attach image in body of gmail

Tags: android, image, gmail

I want to attach an image in body on gmail, I used below code

```
if(imageuri != null){
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageuri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "150+ Reasons to Quit Smoking");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "www.selftalk.info");
    intent.setType("image/*");
}else{
    intent.setType("plain/text");
}
```

but this just attach the image as attachment and I want to show it in body of gmail. Can anybody tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an HTML mail body and use an IMG tag in there. [You can embed the image in the HTML using base64 encoding](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3927/embedded-images-in-html-email), but this may not work in all mail clients. Alternatively you may reference the image on an external server.

Answer (score -3):

No need of coding.. just open Gmail in browser as a desktop mode.. there is in line option is available.